# Customize the cancel_comment_reply_link

Tags: comment-form

As the title suggests, I want to modify or customize the `cancel_comment_reply_link` without editing the `/wp-includes/comment-template.php`.

The code in `comment-template.php` looks like this:

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">
   <?php comment_form_title( $args['title_reply'], $args['title_reply_to'] ); ?>
        <small>
            <?php cancel_comment_reply_link( $args['cancel_reply_link'] ); ?>
       </small>
</h3>
```

Basically, I want to get the `cancel_comment_reply_link` out of the `<h3>` and `<small>`-Tags into a `<div>` container but I really don't know how to achieve this without touching `comment-template.php`.

Is there a solution to include into my theme's `functions.php`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but there might be a simple CSS solution to solve your challenge.  You might get several solutions if you describe what you are trying to do.  Otherwise, writing your own plugin to modify WP core functionality here.

Comment: The output around there is horrible pain to customize (you'll need to buffer output or fork it altogether). :(

Comment: Why not just use Jquery?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Although the post says,`1 year ago`, but maybe someone needs to know how, so I will share my knowledge.

You may create a file, named `comments.php` in your active themes's root directory and make changes to it:

```
<h3>Comment form title</h3>
<p><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></p>
<form id="commentform" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
    <?php
        comment_id_fields();
        do_action('comment_form', $post->ID);
    ?>
</form>
```